# GHC Haskell duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: haskell, ghc

If I follow an example in Real World Haskell (JSON example) and I first omit the mistake of the brackets in the module, when I compile I still het the following error

> ld: 38 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) `gcc'
>   failed in phase`Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

Anybody any idea what that is and how to resolve? Any one had this problem in the Real World Haskell tut as well?

Answer (score 6):

Thread can be closed: if compiled with omitting the object file it seems to be OK. Verified this and seems to be a difference in versions of GHC

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have "threads"; It has Questions and Answers. Your current question doesn't fit the format for questions, and this doesn't fit the format for an answer. For now this isn't a problem (for you) since your current problem is resolved, but going forward I recommend you check out the Help Center and other questions and answers on this website to get a feeling for how to write useful questions and answers.

Comment: This question was useful for me. I am following the same tutorial (Real World Haskell) and encountered this error. Google returns this page at the top of a list if I put the error message in the search bar. And the solution works. I only suggest @Madderote to add an example to the answer, to make it clear that there is no need to include the SimpleJSON.o object file in the command line since the SimpleJSON module already imported in the source file.

Comment: To be absolutely clear - run `ghc -o simple Main.hs` without the object file.